# Extract Portion From A Decimal

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to extract any value > .5 from a decimal.  Here is sample ddl

```
Create Table #b
(
  fv decimal(16,4)
  fv1 decimal(16,4)
)

Insert Into #b (fv) Values ('.8032')
```

How can I capture the .3032 and insert it into fv1?

Comment: Hi, This question needs more detail. Is this the only use case, .8032 and .3032? I don't see the question here?

Comment: What happens to values `<= 0.5`? Do those just stay the same in the `fv1` column? Do they become 0? What *should* happen to them...

Comment: @RashidInman Can you add a small text table with sample FV and expected FV1. It will make this question easier to understand and may be useful one day for others with similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace fv1 by a [Computed Column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx):

```
Create Table #b
(
    fv decimal(16,4)
    , fv1 AS ( 
            CASE WHEN fv > 0.5 THEN fv - 0.5 ELSE fv END
        ) PERSISTED
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to set the field fv1 to be 0.5 less than the value in fv?

```
UPDATE #b
SET fv1 = ISNULL(fv, 0.00000) - 0.5
```

You could also make fv1 be a computed column which would make it automatic.

Comment: If fv is NULL, fv1 will be -0.5. It may not be what is expected ? (Question is not clear though...)

Answer (score -1):

Do a modulo 0.5:

```
Insert Into b (fv, fv1) Values (.8032, 0.8032 % 0.5);
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c156d/1)